# Obtaining a HANDLE to a named pipe opened in an external process (win32)

Tags: winapi, named-pipes, handle

I have a logging facility (descendent of SS_Log) that consists of an independent log viewer and a C++ lib to send messages via a named pipe.

The log viewer is launched by the client through the C++ lib, when the 1st message is logged, and does

```
HANDLE hPipe = CreateNamedPipe( szPipeName,
                                PIPE_ACCESS_DUPLEX, 
                                PIPE_TYPE_MESSAGE|PIPE_WAIT|PIPE_READMODE_MESSAGE, 
                                PIPE_UNLIMITED_INSTANCES, 
                                SSLOG_MAX_MESSAGE_LENGTH,
                                0, 5000, &sa );

pView->Pipe(hPipe);

if( pView->Pipe() == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE )
{
    pView->MessageBox( _T("Could not create the pipe for incoming messages.  No messages can be received.   "), 
        _T("Fatal Error"), MB_OK|MB_ICONSTOP );
    return FALSE;
}

// now we loop forever, waiting for messages.  As they come in, send them
// to the SS_Log_WindowView::EraseLog() and SS_Log_WindowView::WriteLog()
// functions as appropriate.
while( TRUE )
{
    ConnectNamedPipe( pView->Pipe(), NULL );
    ...
}
```

When the client wants to send a message, it does

```
BOOL bResult = WaitNamedPipe(WindowPipeName(), 20000);
            bResult = CallNamedPipe(WindowPipeName(), (LPVOID)szFinalBuffer, 
                             _tcslen(szFinalBuffer)+1, (LPVOID)NULL, 
                             0, &dwBytesRead, 
                             5000);
```

I would like to obtain a HANDLE that corresponds to this named pipe. The documentation suggests I could just make one using `CreateFile( WindowPipeName(), GENERIC_READ|GENERIC_WRITE,...OPEN_EXISTING,...)`. When I do that something clearly starts to block, and the log viewer no longer receives any messages. And that's even without doing anything with that HANDLE.

Is it possible to do what I want, and if so, how?

Comment: See the comments section on the `CreateNamedPipe` MSDN page: _"Although MSDN says that pipes can be bidirectional you must not misunderstand this in the sense that both sides can be listening for data at the same time. A ReadFile() executed on both ends of the pipe at the same time may result in the next WriteFile() command hanging forever. "_. `CallNamedPipe` is basically a `WriteFile` followed by a `ReadFile` followed by a `CloseHandle`.

Comment: Heh, of course not - and I wasn't doing any of that AFAIK. I only passed read + write flags to CreateFile to match the mode selected in CreateNamedPipe, but never actually used the file HANDLE.
Why does CallNamedPipe do a ReadFile (and I presume it opens a HANDLE first, if it ends by closing one ;) ) ?

Comment: As by the docs: _"**Connects** to a message-type pipe (and waits if an instance of the pipe is not available), **writes** to and **reads** from the pipe, and then **closes** the pipe."_ So yes, it does all 4 operations, it's what the function is supposed to do. Don't ask me why someone deemed it useful to implement such a function, though.

Comment: To answer my own question on CallNamedPipe: I presume it's supposed to be able to do both reading and writing. Indeed the log viewer app also does a WriteFile on the pipe after having read a message.
Why CallNamedPipe would do a ReadFile if there is no receive buffer is beyond me, though. Possibly because the 'other side' isn't required to know that a connection is unidirectional (but then, why would it be required to know CallNamedPipe is being used? O:-) )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The log viewer's loop starts with a call to `ConnectNamedPipe`.  So it waits for a client to connect, reads a message, returns to the top of the loop and waits for a client to connect again.

This works with `CallNamedPipe` because that function connects and disconnects every time it sends a message.

But if the client creates a persistent connection by opening a handle to the pipe with `CreateFile` then it is only connecting once.  In the server, the second call to `ConnectNamedPipe` will hang waiting for another client to connect.

If you want the log viewer to handle only a single client with a persistent connection you can have a loop that calls `ConnectNamedPipe` followed by an inner loop that handles messages from the client until the pipe is closed.

If you want to handle multiple clients then your current solution is much simpler than attempting to handle multiple simultaneous connections.

Comment: OK, thanks, this explains some other issues I'd seen when logging too frequently ... and that there is no HANDLE on the client side except during the CallNamedPipe calls. BTW, the blocking I noticed was on the client side, the log viewer didn't appear to be blocking as far as menu reactivity allowed to judge.